# How can i convert C# String into Java.Lang.String?

Tags: java, string, xamarin, type-conversion, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin.
And this is the problem. One of the function receives `Java.Lang.String` as its argument and I have `String` of C#. I need to typecast C#'s String into Java's String.

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to convert java String to C# string as it is shown in the title, or you want to convert C# string into Java String as it stated in your question body?

Comment: okay yes, really sorry
as it is stated in the body

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer
This is how we can convert C# String into Java String.
Thanks for every answer.
They all helped in the right direction.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18654/better-way-to-convert-string-to-java-object

Comment: Please do not post answers that are simply links to other sites.

Answer (score 8):

solution:

```
string a = "some_text";
Java.Lang.String javaA = new Java.Lang.String(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to convert the C# string to a neutral type existing in both c# and Java. so, you can either use a byte array some type of sql type (like a CLOB), or a mechanism similar to serialisation/deserialisation.